# why Java 8 :: operator not working for Object hashcode method when we use super?

Tags: java, java-8

Below code working

```
Function fun1= super::equals
Function fun2= Object::hashCode
```

But below code is not

```
Function fun1= Object::equals
Function fun2= super::hashCode
```

What is the concept here even though all are instance methods in Object class.

I have read somewhere the principals are:

1. object::instance methods
2. Class::static method
3. Class:: instance Method

Comment: Can you expand on "Not working"?

Comment: One thing that you've clearly missed there(in the concepts) is the type. You're using raw types.

Comment: I'm getting compiler error saying that " the type Object does not define hashCode(Object) that is applicable here.

Comment: Well, you have used `super` here. Could you please edit the question to share further details about the parent class and the context around the code you've shared.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Dont put more information into comments, edit the question instead.

Answer (score 11):

The `Function` interface is a functional interfaces representing a function that accepts one parameter and returns a value.

`super::equals` works because it is a function that accepts one parameter and returns a value.

`Object::equals` does not work because it is a function that accepts ***two*** parameters and returns a value.

If you have a method reference of the form `ClassName::instanceMethod`, the function that it represents will have an extra parameter - the object on which to call the method. According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

> The equivalent lambda expression for the method reference `String::compareToIgnoreCase` would have the formal parameter list `(String a, String b)`, where `a` and `b` are arbitrary names used to better describe this example. The method reference would invoke the method `a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)`

`super::equals` is of the form `instance::instanceMethod` so there is no problem and works as you expect.

The correct functional interface types to use for `Object::equals` and `super::hashCode` is `BiFunction<Object, Object, Boolean>` and `IntSupplier`.

Also, don't use raw types.

Comment: If Object:: equals is expecting 2 parameters and because of that it is not working,then why Object:: hashCode is working it is not expecting any I perameter

Comment: @Balrajgoud Because `Function` expects only one parameter.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that `Function fun2= Object::hashCode;` compiles, because it takes the current instances as the argument part of the function, but doesn't pass it to `hashCode` and instead calls that method on the instance?

Comment: @Tom Yes, see the quoted documentation.

Comment: @Tom yes, that instance is not passed as a parameter but used as the instance that the method is applied to.

Comment: Wow, never realized that. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Balrajgoud Are you still quite confused about this? If so, please tell me. Otherwise please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.Function` is a function which takes *one* argument.

`super::equals` is a function which takes *one* argument (the object which is `super` compared to), hence it works. `Object::equals` is a function which takes *two* arguments:  the target object and the object to compare to, hence it doesn't work.

Similarly, `Object::hashCode` is a function of one argument, but `super::hashCode` is a function of *zero* arguments.

Comment: Alright, I think what you're also trying to point out is the representation using method reference there in which case you're right.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `super::methodName`, you are creating a method reference on a specific instance of a class. Therefore, the method of the functional interface (that you assign this method reference to) must expect the same number of parameters as `methodName` has.

When you write `ClassName::methodName`, if `methodName` is not a static method, you are creating a method reference on an arbitrary instance of a class. Therefore, the method of the functional interface (that you assign this method reference to) must expect the same number of parameters as `methodName` has + 1 (the extra parameter being the instance of ClassName on which the method will be executed).

`Function` takes one argument and returns a value.

Hence you can assign to it a method reference of a specific instance and a single argument method (as in `super::equals`) or a method reference of an arbitrary instance and a 0 argument method (as in `Object::hashCode`).

You can't, however, assign to it a method reference of an arbitrary instance and a single argument method (as in `Object::equals`), since that requires two arguments, and `Function` expects just one.

Since two arguments are expected, you can assign this method reference to a `BiFunction`:

```
BiFunction<Object,Object,Boolean> bifunc = Object::equals;
```

Similarly, you can't assign to it a method reference of a specific instance and a 0 argument method (as in `super::hashCode`), since that requires 0 arguments, and `Function` expects one.

Since 0 arguments are expected, you can assign this method reference to a `Supplier`:

```
Supplier<Integer> sup = super::hashCode;
```

Comment: Minor improvement, instead of `Supplier<Integer>` one could use `IntSupplier`, but else, great explanation, like always ;) +1

Comment: @Lino well, both `IntSupplier` and `Supplier<Integer>` are suitable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

hashCode is not a Function. it is a supplier.

```
Supplier fun2 = super::hashCode;
```

Comment: `hashCode` is not a method ! You sure??

Comment: @CommonMan 'hashCode' is not a method? what are you talking about?

Comment: Object.hashCode(); is what?

Comment: I missed the sarcasm in your comment. Didn't see the error you were commenting on. But technically, he is right. hashCode is a method, not a function, and he did claim hashCode is not a function :)

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize, the method references are as follows:

- `super::equals` is equivalent to `Function<Object, Boolean> f = a -> super.equals(a)`.
- `Object::hashCode` is equivalent to `Function <Object, Integer> f = a-> Object.hashCode(a)`.
- `super::hashCode` is equivalent to `Supplier<Integer> f = () -> super.hashCode()`
- `Object::equals` is equivalent to `BiFunction<Object, Object,Boolean> f = (a, b) -> a.equals(b)`.

Note that your variable type is incompatible to lambda signature.